# Facebook Graph API: Get public events from venue (without FQL)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use the graph api with FQL with the query below (PHP)

```
$graph_url= 'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q='.urlencode(
'SELECT
creator,eid,location,pic_cover,name,description,start_time,end_time,
location,ticket_uri,venue FROM event 
WHERE eid IN 
   (SELECT eid FROM event 
     WHERE contains("'.$name.'") and creator = '.$venue_id.' )
     AND start_time >= now() 
     ORDER BY start_time 
     ASC').
'&access_token='.$access_token.'';
```

The query above returns all events from a given venue id / name. This works perfect for me.
However, I read that FQL is deprecated. I read the API documentation but I'm clueless how I can 'replicate' this query to a valid Graph API query.(without FQL)

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, it was pretty simple actually.

```
$graph_url= 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$venue_id.'/events?fields=id,cover,name,description,start_time,end_time,location,ticket_uri,venue&limit=1000&since='.$date.'&access_token='.$access_token.'';
```